# How to limit input integer in single digit? [python]

Tags: python

what's the easiest way to limit this code integer input to a single digit?

```
num = ["First","Second","Third"]
num_list = []
for a in num:
    x = int(input(f"Enter Your {a} number: "))
    num_list.append(x)

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for k in range(0,3):
            if(i!=j&j!=k&k!=i):
                print(num_list[i],num_list[j],num_list[k])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick fix

```
def get_single_digit_input():
    while True:
        a = input('please enter number')
        if not a.isnumeric():
            print('please enter single digit Numeric only')
            continue
        a = int(a)
        # your logic is here
        if a<=9 and a>=0:
            return a
        else:
            print('please enter single digit Numeric only')

a = get_single_digit_input()
```

Comment: wouldn't this fail when i give `a` as an input?

Comment: yes i have mentioned that it is a quick fix just check the input using .isnumeric()

Answer (score 0):

You can check using a while statement. If the input is not a single digit, force it back to the input statement. Also you want to check if the input is a digit and not an alphabet or special character.

Here's a way to do it: I am using the walrus operator in python 3.9

```
while len(x:=input('Enter a single digit :')) > 1 or (not x.isnumeric()):
    print ('Enter only a single digit')
print (x)
```

If you are using python < 3.9, then use this.

```
x = ''
while True:
    x = input ('Enter a single digit :')
    if (len(x) == 1) and (x.isnumeric()): break
    print ('Enter only a single digit')
print (x)
```